# If condition stopped working in my Java page connecting database

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, tomcat6

```
public String function(String person, String area){
System.out.println("area"+area); //verified "null" is obtained here
if(area==null){
    System.out.println("case1:"+area);
}
return area;    
}
```

I am not getting the print specified inside the if condition why is it happening? it is a database connecting page consists of 2100 lines of codes. can any one tell me possible reason for this? am really fed up with this. it was working fine before. :(

Comment: could it be that area is "null" and not null?

Comment: i had also tried if(area=="null") but no result. :(

Comment: because you compare the reference with == and not the values. Use equal. See my answer...

Comment: If you really want to check (and print) whether the if condition is true or not, you should output the check result: `System.out.println(area == null)`.

Comment: it is returning false, why?

Comment: because area is a string of that form "null" and not null. your database returns it as "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be that area is "null" and not null?

if that is the case and area is a database value of type varchar try this:

```
if(area==null || area.toLowerCase().equals("null")){
```

btw. not sure if `toLowerCase` is needed.

and by the way :-) this is much better.

```
if(area==null || "null".equals(area.toLowerCase())){
```

anyway. null safetyness is not necessary because of the area==null.

if `area` is null the whole `if condition` will be true.

Comment: 'if("null".equals(area.toLowerCase())){}' this much is enough :)

Comment: no I would first check if area is null. after that do the second check. Maybe with a newer db version the return value will be null and then you would get a NullPointerException.